# Encountering "The application which this project type is based on was not found." after migrating solution to Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to open a solution that involves an MVC project in Visual Studio that was developed in VS 2010. After I open the solution, I get this error:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types
may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 

For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets,
please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
```

The migration report contains this message:

```
The application which this project type is based on was not found. 
Please try this link for further information: 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325
```

I tried the following approaches (in no particular order)

1. Repair VS
2. Run `devenv /Setup` in the solution directory
3. Delete the `.user` file associated with the project
4. Repeat of all of those steps after rebooting my computer
5. Install MVC 3 and create an MVC project as described in the link in the migration report. Here, the described files (e.g `/Views/Web.config`) don't seem to exist.

What changes do I need to make to make the MVC project compatible?

Not sure what code/config files I would need for this, but please comment on any further info that could be helpful.

Comment: For a project that old I would definitely not expect VS 2019 to play nice with it.

Comment: How many projects are in the solution? Is it just an ASP.NET MVC project, or are there others?

Comment: There are three other projects in the solution. The first two are a Class Library and a Windows Application. The other one has a `.msi` output, so I'm assuming it's an installer of some sort.

Comment: And what happens if you remove that installer project from the solution, then try to open the solution from VS?

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same issue migrating a VB.net project from VS 2013 to VS 2017. Seems as if there's no easy way around this issue.